# How I do know if my cat is male or female?

Tags: cats, identification

I have a cat called ***Tesla***, who's only 3 months.

We can't see if ***Tesla*** has got testicles or another things because ***Tesla*** has got a *very long* hair.

We asked to our neighbors (they have two cats) how we can now the sex of the cat by only looking ***Tesla***'s colors.

***Tesla*** has got a white hair with black parts and a little bit of brown on it.

Our neighbors said:
- If the cat has got **three** colours, the cat is female.
- If the cat is has got **two** colors, the cat is male.

But we aren't sure about our cats is male, because the cat is flirting with wild cats that they live arround our house.

Can anybody tell me if the cat is *male* or *female*?

Comment: If the question was changed to specifically ask about adult cats this might be a non-duplicate.